# React useState hook race condition with array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So my component is set up as a container that can have x number of children, the user cannot progress until each of the child components is "ready" based on various conditions. I am running into a problem where some of them are set to ready on initial render with no condition needing to be met. If 2 of these are in the same container they each grab the same array with say [false, false] and then one set [true, false] and the other [false, true] and then [false, true] is what gets set in state. I assume this is a result of async setting the state so it grabs the old state value in both calls. How can I fix this?

```js
  const [readyArray, setReadyArray] = useState(
    new Array(children.length).fill(false)
  );

  const setReady = (val, idx) => {
    let newArray = Array.from(readyArray);
    newArray[idx] = val;
    if (isArrayTrue(newArray)) {
        props.setReady(true);
     }
    setReadyArray(newArray);
  };
```

Edit: The function also checks if the entire array is a true and calls another function to let a HOC know that every child is ready.

Comment: I assume the problems is a `react component life cycle problem`, rather than a `state racing condition`, even u r correct, react state is async setting.  \n the problem is the component state will dependents on the children length, which give u the life cycle problem. The fix is not to use children.length, instead using a big number which always larger than your children length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have `setReadyArray` use a callback instead of using the `readyArray` in the closure - this way, immediate state updates won't overwrite each other:

```
const setReady = (val, idx) => {
  setReadyArray(readyArray => readyArray.map(
    (orig, i) => i === idx ? orig : val
  ));
};
```

Comment: i do not think can help.

Comment: There is a further complication, I also check in that function if the array is entirely true and if it is then call another function that is passed down in props. I've modified your code to this ```setReadyArray((readyArray) => {
      let newArray = readyArray.map((orig, i) => (i === idx ? orig : val));
      if (isArrayTrue(newArray)) {
        props.setReady(true);
      }
      return newArray;
    });``` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user3645925 this check should happen in a separate `useEffect`.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for the case where there is only a single element? In the case of 2 elements calling at the same time it appears to work perfectly though.

Comment: Fixed it, needed to be !== instead of === they reversed the ternary operator true/false places